# MySQL Compare Tables and generate delta

Tags: mysql

I have two exact tables with different data. I need to be able to generate a Mysql View with the following:

1. All new rows that don't appear in `previous_table` but appears in `current_table`.
2. All rows in `previous_table` that has updated column values in `current_table`.

The tables don't have any primary keys. I cannot change the schema because it is out of my control.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS
SELECT *
FROM current_table
WHERE (column1, column2, ...) NOT IN
      (SELECT column1, column2, ...
       FROM previous_table);

UNION

SELECT *
FROM previous_table
WHERE (column1, column2, ...) IN
      (SELECT column1, column2, ...
       FROM current_table);
```

In the above example, column1, column2, ... represents the columns that you want to use to determine the uniqueness of rows. You need to replace these placeholders with the actual column names from your tables.

This view will include all the new rows that don't appear in the previous_table but appear in the current_table. It will also include rows from the previous_table that have updated column values in the current_table.

Comment: While possibly correct, a code-only answer helps the person who asked the question, it doesn't do them or future visitors any good.   Please consider improving your answer. See [Is there any benefit in code-only answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274/183937)

Answer (score 1):

Query 1:

```
SELECT *
    FROM current_table AS c
    LEFT JOIN previous_table AS p USING(some-combo-of-columns)
    WHERE (any-NOT-NULL-column-in-p) IS NULL;
```

It is quite naughty not to have a `PRIMARY KEY` on every table.  Do you have a `UNIQUE` key?  Such would work just as well (for this task).

Query 2:

```
SELECT c.*
    FROM current_table AS c
    LEFT JOIN previous_table AS p USING(some-combo-of-columns)
    WHERE (OR-of-!=-comparing-any-columns-that-might-be-different)
```

Please have more specifics in your question; then I can provide more specifics.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any primary key, how do you compare the rows, via all attributes?

```
SELECT ... FROM current_table ct
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM previous_table pt
    WHERE ct.col1 = pt.col1 AND ...
)
UNION ALL
SELECT ... FROM previous_table pt
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM current_table ct
    WHERE ct.col1 = pt.col1 AND ... AND ct.colx <> pt.colx AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM current_table t1
LEFT JOIN previous_table t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
                           AND t1.field2 = t2.field2
                     --    another fields in tables structures
                           AND t1.fieldN = t2.fieldN
WHERE t2.fieldX IS NULL /* fieldX - any field defined as NOT NULL */
```

2)

```
SELECT t2.*, 
       t1.fieldZ -- new value
FROM current_table t1
INNER JOIN previous_table t2 ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
                            AND t1.field2 = t2.field2
                      --    another static fields in tables structures
                            AND t1.fieldN = t2.fieldN
                      --    altered field
                            AND t1.fieldZ != t2.fieldZ
                      /* if more than one field may be changed, then
                            AND (     t1.fieldZa != t2.fieldZa
                                   OR t1.fieldZb != t2.fieldZb
                               --  OR ...
                                )
                      */
```